# Issue finding razor pages from Razor class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, shared, razor-class-library

I have .net core app using razor pages that references a Razor class library (RCL). Everything seems to be working fine. Intelisense is able to find it when I use the `@using` directive and I can use models and functions from the RCL in the main application without any errors. The problem is that the RCL also have razor pages that I want to use but that part is not working. At the top of my _layout.cshtml I have this `@using SharedContent.Pages.Organizations;`, and a link `<a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/SharedContent/Pages/Organizations/Index">Org settings</a>`. When the page renders, the href for the link is blank. When I try to see if I can access the page directly via the URL using the given path it gives me a 404 error. I have checked to make sure the RCL dll is included and it is, I also inspected the DLL to make sure the it has the files and it does (see images below). On the razor page I added @page directive, `@page "/Pages/Organizations/Index" to make sure the the routing is correct in case there are conflicts with other razor pages with the name Index or Edit. I am using both` AspNetCore.App`and`NETCore.App`. Is there some other configuration that I am missing?

**UPDATE:** It seems the the RCL is not generating the the views.dll that is needed and the `Generate views in output directory` and the `Razor Compile` can't be found.

[image]
[image]